# Error Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and api

Tags: android, build, android-studio-3.0

Recently I Have updated android studio with build tools and apis.

While syncing current project i am getting error like:
"Error Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation and 'api'.
how to fix this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a Complete solution for this issue. here is a simple explanation for changes in you build.gradle file.

- You have to replace **compile** with **api** where ever you are using any api ref. like: volley, GitHub dependancy.**strong text**
- You have to replace **compile** with **implementation** where ever you are using android library like play-services-maps,appcompat-v7 etc

[ref](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration?utm_source=android-studio#new_configurations)

Answer (score 4):

The `compile` configuration is deprecated, so you will have to use `implementation` configuration instead. Under dependencies, in your app module's build.gradle, replace `compile` with `implementation`.